# How to read the substring between two expressions and by multiple matching javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

For example:

```
<div id="foo_expression1_bar" ></div>

<div id="foo_expression3_bar" ></div>

<div id="foo_expression7_bar" ></div>
```

I want to get `expression1`,`expression3` and `expression7`

I prefer to do it with `match()` but I can't make it work..

Comment: Please post the code you've tried already.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dat = text.match( /foo_([^_]*)_bar/ );
```

Comment: This code returns an array, with only the first desired value, like so: `["foo_expression1_bar", "expression1"]` -- where the "foo_expression1_bar" is unwanted.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code should help:   [See it in action at jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Wb3KW/)

```
<html>
<body>

    <div id="foo_expression1_bar" ></div>

    <div id="foo_expression3_bar" ></div>

    <div id="foo_expression7_bar" ></div>

    <script>
    var regexp = new RegExp('foo_(.*?)_bar');
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
        console.log(regexp.exec(divs[i].getAttribute('id'))[1]);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Some comments:

- `regexp.exec()` returns array of matches.
- To execute this code you will need any developer extension with console (Chrome's "tools for programmers", Firebug in Firefox or Opera dragonfly).
- First element contains whole matched word, second one text matched by parentheses.
- You can find more information about regexp, see ["JavaScript RegExp Object"](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp).

Answer (score 0):

```
var blah = "foo_expression1_bar";
blah = blah.match(/[_](.*)[_]/)[1]
document.body.innerHTML = blah;
```

that will do it... more detail could result in a little less messy solution though :(

http://jsfiddle.net/m4p3T/

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/EdJyX/ It's usually a good idea to mention what [`console`](http://getfirebug.com/logging) is and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

A variant to the other answers, this one will only capture expression inside the id attribute of a div tag. Also assumes that the expression you are after is after the between the 1st and 2nd '_' characters in the attribute value.

`'<div id="foo_expression1_bar" ></div>'.match(/<div\s+[^>]*id="(.*?)"\s+[^>]*>/i)[1].split('_')[1];`